# How to set quantity of elements of the char array of a variable

Tags: c++, arrays, winapi, char

How to set quantity of elements of the char array of a variable?

This is my code:

```
long int len = strlen(qq);
//char buff[10];
//sprintf(buff, "%d", len);
//MessageBoxA(0,buff,0,0);


char key[len] = "12345678901234567890123456789..";//error
char crypt[len];//error


for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     crypt[i] = text[i] ^ key[i];
}
```

Comment: How about using `std::string` or `std::vector`?

Comment: I need without using std

Comment: C++ doesn't actually have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). If you want a "variable-length array" either use `std::vector` or, as you are working with strings, `std::string`.

Comment: Can't use the standard library? Why? You do know that [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) have an [overloaded array-indexing operator `[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at), so you can use e.g. `someStdStringObject[x]`? And you can easily get a [C-style pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to the underlying string if you need it as well.

Comment: Then allocate dinamically. `char *key = new char[len];` Don't forget `delete[] key;` after finished using the buffer and before the pointer `key` vanishes.

Comment: If you want to use WinApi: `char *key = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, len);` and after finished using `HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, key);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ an array can only be staticly sized using a constant variable that is known at compile time, which your `len` is not. Note that some compiler extensions DO allow this, as it's allowed in C. But for pure C++ you instead can use dynamic memory allocation (this allocates on the heap instead of the stack):

```
char* key = new char[len];
char* crypt = new char[len];
```

Note that a `char*` can be used the same as a `char[]` (you can still use array indexing, the rest of your code remains unchanged).

Because the array is now allocated on the heap, to avoid memory leaks you must manually free the memory when you no longer need it using `delete` e.g. at the end of the function after you loop:

```
delete[] key;
delete[] crypt;
```

Comment: It's better to use standard containers and avoid the need for manual lifetime management

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified the `winapi` tag, it may be that the [`CString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315043(v=vs.60).aspx) class would be a viable solution.

For your `key` though, you don't even need to allocate an array dynamically. You could use the `modulo` operator:

```
static const char key[] = "1234567890";
const size_t keyLength = strlen(key);

CString crypt(0, len);

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  crypt[i] = text[i] ^ key[i & keyLength];
}
```

Comment: `CString` is not part of Windows API.

Comment: @M.M Sure (and it's subject to the `UNICODE` definition, which may become problematic down the road). I was going out on a limb here when guessing what string classes might be acceptable to the OP given that he tagged both [tag:c++] and [tag:winapi].

Comment: If generic text mappings could become problematic (why, incidentally?), use explicit character encodings: `CStringA` or `CStringW`. Again, not part of the Windows API, and not available outside of Visual Studio. If you want to address the [tag:c++] tag, you should really suggest `std::string`/`std::wstring` instead.

Comment: @IInspectable I concur, but the OP wrote `I need without using std` in a comment to his question, which is why refrained from mentioning `std::string` (or `std::wstring`).

Comment: This does not explain, why you propose using a random other library. You cannot just use ATL/MFC's `CString` class template in every Windows API application.